# Zend_Form and Decorator help

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, zend-decorators

```
<select name="day" id="day">
         <option value="0" label="Day:">Day:</option>
         <option value="1" label="1">1</option>
 </select>

 <select name="month" id="month">
  <option value="0" label="Month:">Month:</option>

   <option value="1" label="January">January</option>

  </select>

 <select name="year" id="year">  
    <option value="2010" label="2010">2010</option>
 </select>
```

Can I build a form part like this format using Zend_Form and Decorator? I have read many posting but couldn't find any which helps to pack **more than one elements together inside a "dd" tag.**  Does it possible or not?

Comment: The code above does not show any DD elements. Do you want to have no DD elements at all or do you want to have all three SELECT elements in one single DD?

Comment: Need to show all three SELECT within one SINGLE DD

Comment: <dt>Birthday</dt><dd>Three SELECT</dd>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://weierophinney.net/matthew/archives/217-Creating-composite-elements.html
This post goes onto explain how to create a composite object using Zend_Form_element and settings up custom decorators.
It is also built around having all date fields grouped together so you could probably just modify this example to get what you want.

Comment: Ballasacian, thank you for the link. It helps me to understand the concept. And sorry for the delay in replying.